# i have an error which i dont understand. can you help me?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

what i have in"reportsTo" is similar to employeeNumber so waht is the problem?

```
SELECT firstName,lastName,temp.count
FROM employees
where employeeNumber  in(

SELECT reportsTo, COUNT( * ) AS count
FROM employees
GROUP BY reportsTo
) as temp
```

Comment: You tell us. What's the error you are getting?

Comment: EmployeeNumber **CAN NOT** be `IN` two different those two different Columns or in your case a column and a calculated value.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes your actual question. "i have an error which i dont understand. can you help me?" is totally useless to future readers who find it in a search result when trying to solve their problem, and it gives no information whatsoever about the question you're asking here.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as temp LIMIT 0, 30' at line 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sub queries used for the IN clause can't return multiple columns, so you can't have `SELECT reportsTo, COUNT( * ) AS count` inside it. You probably want to join the subquery instead, something like this:

```
SELECT firstName,lastName,temp.count
FROM employees
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT reportsTo, COUNT( * ) AS count
    FROM employees
    GROUP BY reportsTo
) temp ON employees.employeeNumber = temp.reportsTo
```

Disclaimer: I don't use MySQL so the above syntax may not be exact.

You'll likely also run into issues trying to use `count` as a column name. Either rename it or escape it (SQL Server uses `[` and `]`, not sure about MySQL).

Comment: thanks man! but what i meant to, is similar to join so please explaine me the difference because i dont get it...

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know what you wan't but just change it to:

```
SELECT firstName,
       lastName
  FROM employees 
 WHERE employeeNumber  in( SELECT reportsTo 
                             FROM employees 
                         GROUP BY reportsTo )
```

Deleting the count and the alias will work but I feel that what you really want is:

```
SELECT manager.firstName,
       manager.lastName,
       temp.count        AS number_of_directs
  FROM (SELECT reportsTo, 
               COUNT( * ) AS count
          FROM employees
      GROUP BY reportsTo) as temp
INNER JOIN employees AS manager ON manager.reportsTo = temp.reportsTo
```